# QQ social network API - retrieve user information + upload photo

Tags: php, api

I build an app for Chinese social network QQ and need some help with retrieving user information such as Firstname, Lastname, Age, Gender, ID and also upload function.
Could you give me some directions? Maybe there is some source tutorials or something else in english..
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's available on QQ site. http://wiki.open.qq.com/wiki/API%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8

Comment: Yeah, but is there available English language?

Comment: I don't see English manual. You may want to use Google translate. The API manual is quite easy to understand (I hope).

Comment: Try this link http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.open.qq.com%2Fwiki%2FAPI%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8 :)

Comment: Maybe you know someone who can give this code to me? I'm ready to pay